# Can Rails cause MySQL data to disappear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, innodb, mysql-5.1

I have the most bizarre scenario that I have ever witnessed.  I have a hosted website on a virtual server with Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9 and MySQL 5.1 using InnoDB but not per table.  All of a sudden and for no apparent reason (that I can put my finger on) ALL my data from every table in the database has gone.  The ONLY table not affected is the migrations table created and maintained by Rails only.

The mad thing is that ALL of the table definitions are fine including Index definitions.  After the problem I can add more data to any table and that survives but the data just went.  I do have a previous day data dump that I can restore from but there has been work done since then that I would also like to keep.

I've posted this on the MySQL InnoDB forum and had no response in the last 24 hours. Is it remotely possible that Rails can have a hiccup which could produce this symptom?

Answer (score -1):

I am both relieved and embarrassed. Somehow the 'db' directory under the root of my rails site on my dev m/c got moved to the 'app' directory.  I then copied the tarred version of the 'app' directory to my remote hosted site.  So at the remote site there was a 'db' directory under the rails root AND there was a 'db' directory under 'app'.

The amazing thing is that the site continued to work normally on the dev m/c but clobbered the mysql database on the remote m/c due to the duplicate directory.

I would very much like to understand why the existence of the duplicate 'db' directory on the 'app' directory on the remote m/c caused the above problem.  I would have expected Rails to simply look for the 'db' directory under the rails root directory and ignore the duplicate directory under app.

In fact I would have expected the site to not load on my local dev m/c since the 'db' directory was no longer under the rails root where rails would have been looking for it.

Any way I just thought I'd leave a note of my STUPIDITY in case someone else gets hit with this odd ball problem ever.

Comment: Since this is the solution, would you click on the tick icon to the left of it, to accept it as the answer? This marks the question as answered.